# How to avoid the overlapping of the button?

Tags: css, button, responsive-design

The button is overlapping when navigating the menu (mobile version). Supposedly the button should be place only at the bottom of the pciture (before the white bg). How to fixed this?

CSS (mobile version)

```
.home-header-button {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 13em auto;
    width: 90%;
    top: 25em;
}
```

Link: http://www.homecredit.ph/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `position: relative` to your `.home-header-div`. This will trap the button within that container so that it will get pushed down along with the content when you click on the menu.

Hope this helps.